# Have interface extend string functionality

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp, gulp-inject

I'm using these tools together:

- TypeScript
- Gulp
- Gulp-Inject

I'm trying to do the following:

```
module My {
    interface IGulpInjectable extends string { // << Problem here!
        [gulp_inject: string] : string;
    }

    export class Cache {
        private items: { [key: string] : IGulpInjectable };

        constructor() {
            this.items = {
                "item1": { gulp_inject: "file1.html" },
                "item2": { gulp_inject: "file2.html" }
            }
        }

        getItem(key: string){
            return this.items[key].trim();
        }
    }
}
```

What `gulp-inject` does is replace `{ gulp_inject: "x.html" }` with a string containing the file contents. This is why I want to have `IGulpInjectable` extend `string`: so that methods like `trim()` will be understood by TypeScript.

However, `extends string` is not valid. Neither is `extends String`. At least, not with my current constructor code, which I prefer not to change.

How can I tell TypeScript that my interface has all methods a `string` has?

---

Footnote, my current workaround:

```
        getItem(key: string){
            return (<any> this.items[key]).trim();
        }
```

But that's not quite satisfying.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works fine in typescript playground:

```
interface IGulpInjectable extends String 
{ 
    gulp_inject: string;
}

class Cache 
{
    private items: { [key: string] : IGulpInjectable };


    constructor() 
    {

        let item1 = new String("   123   ");
        item1["gulp_inject"] = "file1.html";

        let item2 = new String("   4556  ");
        item2["gulp_inject"] = "file2.html";

        this.items = {
            "item1": <IGulpInjectable>item1,
            "item2": <IGulpInjectable>item2
        }
    }

    getItem(key: string)
    {
        return this.items[key];
    }
}

let c = new Cache();
let i = c.getItem("item1");
console.log(i.trim()); //output '123'
console.log(i.gulp_inject); //output 'file1.html'
```

Link: [typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=%20%20%20%20interface%20IGulpInjectable%20extends%20String%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20gulp_inject%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20class%20Cache%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20private%20items%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%20%3A%20IGulpInjectable%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20item1%20%3D%20new%20String(%22%20%20%20123%20%20%20%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20item1%5B%22gulp_inject%22%5D%20%3D%20%22file1.html%22%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20item2%20%3D%20new%20String(%22%20%20%204556%20%20%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20item2%5B%22gulp_inject%22%5D%20%3D%20%22file2.html%22%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.items%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22item1%22%3A%20%3CIGulpInjectable%3Eitem1%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22item2%22%3A%20%3CIGulpInjectable%3Eitem2%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20getItem(key%3A%20string)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.items%5Bkey%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20let%20c%20%3D%20new%20Cache()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20i%20%3D%20c.getItem(%22item1%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(i.trim())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(i.gulp_inject)%3B)

Hope this helps.

Comment: But you had to change up the internals of the `constructor` *a lot*. If I want to leave that as is, your typing does *not* work. See [TypeScript playground](bit.ly/1TNQGwP). I'm looking to (learn how to) create a typing for *existing* code, which is why I'd prefer not to change the internals.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing to:

```
interface String extends String{
    [gulp_inject: string] : string;
}
```

Comment: Haven't tried it yet in my own setup, but on its own that code block [isn't okay according to the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=interface%20string%20extends%20string%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bgulp_inject%3A%20string%5D%20%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D)?

Comment: I changed it to `String`, how about now? [shows error but compiles and runs](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=interface%20String%20extends%20String%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bgulp_inject%3A%20string%5D%20%3A%20string%3B%0A%09foo()%3Avoid%3B%0A%7D%0A%0AString.prototype.foo%20%3D%20function()%7B%0A%09console.log('1')%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20a%3Astring%20%3D%20%22asda%22%3B%0Aa.foo()%3B)