# typescript - difficulty "extending" IAngularStatic

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I asked a question similar to this not long ago and got a great deal of help, but even with the answer there I'm struggling with this code.

I've written - in `typescript` - a small service to use with `google api` (*gapi*) and an interface to go with it, listed as this in my code;

## gapiService.ts

```
class GoogleAuthenticationService implements IGoogleAuthenticationService {
   // ...
}

interface IGoogleAuthenticationService extends ng.IServiceProvider { }
```

Now, I can use them like this, but for OCD purposes, I want to attach them to the `angular` namespace/module to be part of the `ng` loading. So I could call them...

```
ng.GoogleAuthenticationService
ng.IGoogleAuthenticationService
```

I thought this would work, but I keep getting the error that it either can't find them or some other error. I've gone through the following list of errors...

- `Property 'GoogleAuthenticationService' does not exist on type 'IAngularStatic'`
- `Module 'angular' has no exported member 'IGoogleAuthenticationService'`
- `An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements.`

Any idea how to achieve what I'm aiming for? It's driving me batty.

## gapiAuth.d.ts

```
declare module 'angular' {
    interface IGoogleAuthenticationService{}
    var GoogleAuthenticationService: GoogleAuthenticationService
}
```

Comment: I guess surrounding your whole code (class plus interface) with `module angular { }` would work

Comment: Look up here, [have-interface-extend-string-functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36031767/have-interface-extend-string-functionality/36067378#36067378)
I assume you ask more or less the same question

Comment: Woah. What is with the declarations in square brackets? That's trippy - I have no idea what those mean.

Comment: No, surrounding it all with `module angular` doesn't work. I get a `duplicate identifier` error.

Answer (score 0):

> ng.GoogleAuthenticationService
>   ng.IGoogleAuthenticationService

Just wrap them in `angular` namespace:

```
namespace angular {
  class GoogleAuthenticationService implements IGoogleAuthenticationService {
     // ...
  }

  interface IGoogleAuthenticationService extends ng.IServiceProvider { }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It makes all other instances of angular wrong.

Comment: I assume because it changes the definition of what `angular` is.

Comment: put them in a new file called `foo.d.ts`. I suspect you are pasting in an existing file that is already a module

Comment: That doesn't work. It just says there's a duplicate identifier.